# FragmentPagerAdapter: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, navigation-drawer

Trying to create application with view pager inside navigation drawer. I've options to select from navigation and depending on that (outer selection), i have to populate different number of fragments in view pager.

I've used tutorials to create navigation drawer and view pager separately from Google docs. As per docs, view pager have fixed number of fragments. if i hard code that way everything works fine.

But, when i try to make it dynamic as per left selection, i'm getting illegal state exception

for instance, I've implemented fragmentstatepageradapter,

```
 public class innerFragment extends Fragment {

    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;
    public static final String active_outer_option = "section_number";

    public innerFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_outer, container,
                false);

        Log.d("logs", "onCreateView:innerFragment()");

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(Integer
                .parseInt(getArguments().getString(active_outer_option)));
        Log.d("logs", "onAttach:innerFragment()");
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        private int active_outer_option= 0;

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);

        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Log.d("logs", "getItem(int " + position + ")");

            active_outer_option = position;
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("section_number", "" + position);
            DummySectionFragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(b);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            switch (active_outer_option) {
            case 0:
                return 9;
            case 1:
                return 2;
            case 2:
                return 2;
            case 3:
                return 2;
            case 4:
                return 4;
            default:
                return 0;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Log.d("logs", "getPageTitle(int " + position + ")");
            return "OP " + String.valueOf(position);
        }

    }

    public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public DummySectionFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            Log.d("logs", "onCreateView:DummySectionFragment()");

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inner,
                    container, false);
            TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView
                    .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            dummyTextView.setText(getArguments().getString(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
            return rootView;
        }

    }

}
```

when i run this application, its giving "Unfortunately application stopped working" and exception is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged! Expected adapter item count: 9, found: 2 Pager id: com.xxx.xxx:id/pager Pager class: class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager Problematic adapter: class com.xxx.xxx.innerFragment$SectionsPagerAdapter
```

any idea whats wrong with that exception and code?

Edit:

from my debugging first everything is fine and gettitle is called twice with index 0 and 1 and after that getcount is called with index  and getting exception.

does this ring any bells?

Comment: From the exception, it seems that you removed some items from the adapter.

Comment: @Sufian i didn't do updated adapter at all. what i could say is first outer selection will give 9 inner options (fragments) and second outer option gives 2 inner options (fragments). what i read from documentation, view pager loads second page for pagination. is that possible issue in my case?

Comment: I'm not sure but I'd say that your `getCount()` returns different values depending upon the value of `active_outer_option`. The PagerAdapter doesn't like this and hence throws the exception.

Comment: Do you want to show a sectioned `ListView` in there?

Comment: i got it figured out. it's business logic mistake. as i expected activity is trying to load second view in view pager and i'm setting that index to active_outer_option which is the mistake. Anyways, Thanks guys.